# Agora ringing issue

Tags: agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

We have two apps, one app call to other app using Agora.
We are facing ringing issue when a call is disconnected within 10 seconds from the first app. The ringing continues for 5-10 seconds even after disconnecting the call. Kindly suggest the troubleshooting steps.